# MySQL - SELECTING COLUMNS ONLY IF THEY HAVE VALUES

Tags: mysql

I need to frame a MySQL query in which there is a requirement to pick columns only if it has value (being **NOT NULL**) out of the 4 columns given, `first_accuracy`, `second_accuracy`, `third_accuracy`, `fourth_accuracy`.

Suppose I have only values for **first_accuracy**, **second_accuracy**, So the query should be

> SELECT first_accuracy, second_accuracy FROM compliance_employees CE;

**UPDATE:**

**Query I applied:**

```
SELECT first_accuracy, second_accuracy, third_accuracy, fourth_accuracy FROM compliance_employees CE;
```

**Result:**

[image]

You could see that for 'Third Accuracy' there is no value for any of the rows, So I don't want to select that column at all. Is that possible?

Any solution?

Comment: I guess `col is not null` ?

Comment: ... `WHERE CE.first_accuracy IS NOT NULL AND CE.second_accuracy IS NOT NULL AND CE.third_accuracy IS NULL AND CE.fourth_accuracy IS NULL`

Comment: You can't do this without using dynamic SQL.  But why do you want to do this?  Just use `COALESCE()` to handle `NULL` values in each of the columns.

Comment: In the UI, we need to discard the columns with empty values and I was assuming that if we could do it using MySQL, pretty well and good.  COALESCE() is not sufficient as it will only replace the NULL values with the given one.

Comment: 'Third Accuracy' column has 'NULL' value or blank spaces ? and all values are in percentage  '%'

Comment: This is actually a WEB view, in Database it has NULL values

Answer (score 3):

Using 'UNION' ,GROUP_CONCAT() and 'not null' we find count of column which have values. 
then pass columns to Prepared statment which give you result whhich you want.

```
        select coalesce (GROUP_CONCAT(col_name),'No_Result') into @ColumnNames
        from (
        select 'first_accuracy' as col_name, count( distinct first_accuracy) as count from compliance_employees
        where first_accuracy  is not null 
        union
        select 'second_accuracy' as col_name, count( distinct second_accuracy) from compliance_employees
        where second_accuracy  is not null
        union
        select 'third_accuracy' as col_name, count( distinct third_accuracy) from compliance_employees
        where third_accuracy  is not null
        union
        select 'fourth_accuracy' as col_name, count( distinct fourth_accuracy) from compliance_employees
        where fourth_accuracy is not null
        )a where count >0\\
        -- select @ColumnNames\\


    SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT ', @ColumnNames, ' FROM compliance_employees');
    set @sql := REPLACE(@sql,'No_Result','"No Column have values" as No_Result')\\

     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
```

Check Live demo [Here](http://rextester.com/SWHKJ15218).

> Output :

[image]

Comment: The query throws error if all fields are null. Otherwise, this is an excellent answer.

Comment: @PrabirGhosh third_accuracy COLUMN have all fields null value .. What are you try to say ?

Comment: Just try with rare condition of all fields of all columns as null. But yours is the best answer according to me.

Comment: @PrabirGhosh Ok. TQ for info. Now Code updated. which can show 'No result' if all columns have data only NULL. Also we can use CASE when for this.

Comment: Thank you very much and let me check it after which I will accept the answer. :)

Comment: No Problem @RajeshOmanakuttan  as per your requirement and input table i have tried query. If any error let us know.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make sure that the two columns `first_accuracy` and `second_accuracy` are not `NULL` then use this:

```
SELECT first_accuracy,
       second_accuracy
FROM compliance_employees CE
WHERE first_accuracy  IS NOT NULL AND
      second_accuracy IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to make sure that *all* four columns are not `NULL` then use this:

```
SELECT first_accuracy,
       second_accuracy
FROM compliance_employees CE
WHERE first_accuracy  IS NOT NULL AND
      second_accuracy IS NOT NULL AND
      third_accuracy  IS NOT NULL AND
      fourth_accuracy IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I guess I did not frame my question well, It is not just 'NOT NULL'..  appreciate your help though..

Comment: @RajeshOmanakuttan This answers your question as you have worded it.  If you mean something else, then update and show us sample data.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    first_accuracy, 
    second_accuracy
FROM
    compliance_employees CE
WHERE 
    first_accuracy IS NOT NULL
    AND second_accuracy IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to ask how to select the value out of four fields? If so, I suggest using `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT 
    GREATEST(first_accuracy, second_accuracy) as accuracy
FROM
    compliance_employees CE;
```