# Select columns only if column values are not identical SQL

Tags: sql, select

I want to select certain columns only if the column values are not identical. The column values may vary and I do not know the exact value they might have beforehand. I also have some columns that I want to select always, no matter what value.

My output data currently looks like this:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E    Column F
1           BB          777         NULL        Louis       0
2           BB          777         NULL        Peter       0
3           BB          777         NULL        Mary        0
4           BB          777         NULL        Paul        0
```

I always want the output to return data from Column A, but Column B, C, D, E and F only if the values are not identical. In this case, I would only want my output data to return columns A and E:

```
Column A    Column E    
1           Louis       
2           Peter      
3           Mary        
4           Paul
```

Columns A, B and C are from Table_X and Columns D, E and F are from Table_Y.

This is what I have written so far, I have only managed the select part:

```
SELECT  Column A
        Column B
        Column C
        Y.Column D
        Y.Column E
        Y.Column F


FROM    Table_X
        INNER JOIN Table_Y AS Y ON Table_X.Id  = Y.Table_XId
```

I have browsed and found some other posts similar to my question, but they do not really match what I want, with not wanting to select identical values no matter what the value is, i.e:
[MySQL - SELECTING COLUMNS ONLY IF THEY HAVE VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498964/mysql-selecting-columns-only-if-they-have-values)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Formatting tip: When editing, type in proper columns, mark all data and click `{}`.

Comment: how did u join table 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Can you share your query written so far?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution.

Count distinct values on each column. Using UNPIVOT, transform columns in rows and select just the rows with multiple values. Put the column names into a string and exec a dinamic query.

```
create table #t (a int, b varchar(max), c varchar(max), d  varchar(max), e  varchar(max), f  varchar(max))
insert into #t 
    select 1,'bb','777',null,'louis','0' union
    select 2,'bb','777',null,'peter','0' union
    select 3,'bb','777',null,'mary','0' union
    select 4,'bb','777',null,'paul','0'

declare @columnsToSelect varchar(max)

select @columnsToSelect = replace(replace(( select columnName
                                            from(
                                                select  b = count(distinct b),
                                                        c = count(distinct c),
                                                        d = count(distinct d),
                                                        e = count(distinct e),
                                                        f = count(distinct f)
                                                from #t) t
                                            unpivot (number_of for columnName IN(b,c,d,e,f)) as unp
                                            where number_of > 1
                                            for xml auto),'<unp columnName="',''),'"/>',',')

if @columnsToSelect is not null begin
    select @columnsToSelect = left(@columnsToSelect, len(@columnsToSelect)-1)
    select @columnsToSelect 

    exec('select a,'+@columnsToSelect+' from #t')
end

drop table #t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query to get the required output

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
DECLARE @ColumnBCount int
DECLARE @ColumnCCount int
DECLARE @ColumnDCount int
DECLARE @ColumnECount int
DECLARE @ColumnFCount int

SELECT @ColumnBCount = COUNT(DISTINCT [ColumnB])
,@ColumnCCount= COUNT(DISTINCT [ColumnC])
,@ColumnDCount= COUNT(DISTINCT [ColumnD])
,@ColumnECount= COUNT(DISTINCT [ColumnE])
,@ColumnFCount=COUNT(DISTINCT [ColumnF])
 FROM Table_X AS X
        INNER JOIN Table_Y AS Y ON X.Id  = Y.Table_XId


SELECT @SQL= 'SELECT ColumnA'
+ CASE WHEN @ColumnBCount>1 THEN ',ColumnB' ELSE '' END
+CASE WHEN @ColumnCCount>1 THEN ',ColumnC' ELSE '' END
+CASE WHEN @ColumnDCount>1 THEN ',ColumnD' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN @ColumnECount>1 THEN ',ColumnE' ELSE '' END
+CASE WHEN @ColumnFCount>1 THEN ',ColumnF' ELSE '' END 
+' FROM Table_X AS X
        INNER JOIN Table_Y AS Y ON X.Id  = Y.Table_XId'


EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: If your column name is not like ColumnA please replace it with the right name( example [Column A] as in the question or any other name.)

Comment: Million thanks for this!!! I have typed and tripple checked that I got it down as you have written it, but I get a warning and an error message. The warning I suppose is because the script will leave out columns that contains only NULL? Which is fine. 

"Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."


However the error message I dont get:

"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'."

I dont even have a word called INNER in state 1 line 2?

Comment: Are you writing script in TSQL or are you using MySQL

Comment: If you are writing query using TSQL in SQL server management then this should work .See the SQL fiddle- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/010b0/2 . I have created 2 tables Table_X and Table_Y and loaded the data you have given above and tested. It works